# tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits how to use labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-science

For an assignment, I'm supposed to write a single layer neural network for one part of it. I think I got most of the stuff right, however when I tried using the tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits method, I got an error saying "ValueError: Both labels and logits must be provided." Which obviously means I need to provide both labels and logits, as I only provided logits in my code right now, so I understand what is wrong. What I don't understand is, what is labels and how I use them in this context? Keep in mind that I'm fairly new and inexperienced in tensorflow and neural networks in general. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm labels are targets. In supervised learning, you provide a target for it to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In supervised learning you have to give labels along with the training data and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits calculates the softmax cross entropy between logits and labels. It helps to give the probability of a data being in a particular class. You can read more about it here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

```
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2    
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
```

I've given you a snippet of code from tensorflow tutorials where`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is used. Here `y_` is a placeholder to which the labels are fed. 
Also `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is currently deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand it. Another part of the assignment that I'm struggling with is that our input has shape=[None,784] and the output is expected to be shape=[None,10] with a one layered network of layersize=10. I created the weights with shape=[layersize,784] and then multiplied with the input and added biases, then put it through softmax. Is that a correct approach?

Comment: Also another thing about the labels, in this assignment we're just creating the network, the training code is handled by the code given to us, and it doesn't supply values for a labels placeholder. How would I get the values for that labels?

Comment: I think it's best of I don't do that, since it's a university assignment. I figured out the placeholder and the label part though, so thanks for that. My problem right now is with tf.matmul. My input placeholder is size None,784 and it's fed 256,784 as far as I can tell from the error, but my weights are [10,784]. I'm getting incompatible matrix size for matmul. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can change the dimensions of weight matrix to match the deimension of your input